# How do I disable Amazon 'similar products'?

Tags: advertisements

After years of ad-free browsing, I am suddenly confronted with Amazon pop-ups on *other* websites. This is self-inflicted, because earlier today I clicked on "Yes" on an Amazon banner on Amazon.com and Amazon.co.uk, thinking it would help me *on those pages alone*.

So how do I get rid of it again?

[image]

Comment: What browser version?  If this is the shopping assistant I am thinking of (Spigot) it can be fairly nasty and invasive.  You can try http://www.go-remove-malware.com/how-to-remove-spigot-toolbar-and-search-redirect/

Comment: @HeXanon Safari for Mac 7.0.3

Comment: I would take a look at the addons and remove anything you don't recognise.

Comment: @HeXanon There are no suspicious extensions or plug-ins.

Comment: You willing to delete the user profile for Safari anyways?  Because what you clicked on likely wasn't generated by Amazon.

Comment: @Ramhound I found it. Superfish.

Comment: @GlenTheUdderboat - As I suspected.  Superfish has nothing to do with Amazon.  I don't know the reason you got a request to install it.

Comment: @Ramhound Since my browser is ad-free and pop-up free, I assumed that the yellow bar on top of the Amazon page was Amazon's. But all the blockers in the world probably don't help against extensions that I install myself. :) Anyway, Amazon is cleared, but I'll leave the question as it is, so that it can be found by others having this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the culprit. It was in an extension I didn't initially think was associated with it. Removed all of it.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/a/403652/302527

Comment: Glad you found it.  I thought it was an extension :)